# wkhtmltopdf page-break-after not working

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf, page-break, phpwkhtmltopdf

I know this has been discussed a lot of times, I tried everything but not success.

Everything I tried just not has any effect, other css working perfectly.
I can't understand why is not break div to a another page.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>    
  <title> PDF </title>
  <style>

*, *:before, *:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
overflow: visible !important;
}

.myrow { 
float:left;
width:100%;
padding:20 10px; 
}

    .pagebreak {
     page-break-after:always;
     clear:both;
     display:block;
     }

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="myrow">
    Content
    </div>
  <div class="myrow">
    Content
    </div>
  <div class="myrow">
    Content
    </div>
  <div class="myrow">
    Content
    </div>

  <div class="pagebreak"></div>

  <div class="myrow">
    Content
    </div>
  <div class="myrow">
    Content
    </div>

  <div class="pagebreak"></div>

  <div class="myrow">
    Content
    </div>
  <div class="myrow">
    Content
    </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

MY PHP

```
$pdf = new Pdf(array(

'margin-top'    => 0,
'margin-right'  => 0,
'margin-bottom' => 0,
'margin-left'   => 0,
'disable-smart-shrinking',
'print-media-type',

));


 $pdf->addPage(page.html);
```

Why is not working?

Comment: I have had the same issue - there is nothing wrong your code. Our testing server refused to show page breaks, however it worked perfectly on the live server. It's related to which version of wkhtmltopdf your server is running.

Comment: Yes, you right, I just updated to last version of wkhtmltopdf and now works.